# How can I read a table with two values (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm working with **Codeigniter**.

My function works, but I want to make a change and I can't figure how to do it.

My function is doing a read where "status_offre_id" = 1.

**But I want it to read "status_offer_id" = 1 AND "status_offer_id" = 2**

So far I tried this:

```
'status_offer_id' => (1 AND 2),
'status_offer_id' => 1,2,
('status_offer_id' => 1) AND ('status_offer_id' => 2), 

and more
```

---

```
<?php  
function showOffer(){

  $idCompany = $_SESSION["company"]["id"];
  $conditions = array(
          'company_id' => $idCompany,
          'status_offer_id' => 1,
    );

  $offer_published = $this->offer_model->lire("*", $conditions);

  $data = array();
  $data["offer"]=$offer_published;

  $this->_layoutHaut();
  $this->load->view('Company/offer_view', $data);
  $this->_layoutBas();
}
?>
```

---

```
  public function lire($selection = "*", $conditions = array(), $champs_order = "id", $direction_ordre = "ASC", $nombre_limite = NULL, $debut_limite = NULL){
$retour= $this->db->select($selection)
                    /*à partir de quelle table*/
                    ->from($this->table)
                    /*déterminer des conditions spécifiques*/
                    ->where($conditions)
                    /*déterminer un ordre précis*/
                    ->order_by($champs_order, $direction_ordre)
                    /*déterminer une limite*/
                    ->limit($nombre_limite, $debut_limite)
                    /*obtenir les résultats (va de pair avec result()*/
                    ->get()
                    /*retourner les résultats sous forme de tableau*/
                    ->result_array();

                    return $retour;
```

}

Comment: I guess for a generic variable it would be "difficult" to assume both "1" AND "2" values at the very same time. Maybe you should check if: "status_offer_id" = 1 OR "status_offer_id" = 2 more than "status_offer_id" = 1 AND "status_offer_id" = 2

Comment: Yes I saw that... I changed it for a OR. The solution of maX worked, but I wondered if it was possible to do with the => ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$conditions = '(company_id = "' . $idCompany . '" AND status_offer_id IN (1, 2))';
```

Comment: I dosen't work : unexpected = (and I also tried with =>)

Comment: Véronique c'est français ça ?! Ce sera plus simple ! Effectivement la première propo que je t'ai faite ne fonctionne pas, j'ai édité ma réponse et c'est je pense la seule solution à ton souci

Comment: Merci! Ça a fonctionné... cependant, j'ai changé le deuxième AND par un OR.

Comment: Oui j'allais te dire tu risques de n'avoir aucun résultats avec ça :) J'ai modifié ma réponse, c'est un poil plus propre

Answer (score 0):

Ur using CI which has active records, try to use them

```
$this->db->select("*")
->from($table)
->where('company_id', $company_id)
->where('status_offer_id', 1)
->or_where('status_offer_id',2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$where = (select * from your_table where status_offer_id IN (1, 2));
$this->db->where('company_id', $company_id);
$this->db->where($where);
```